# Is cricket the second most popular game after football?

Tags: cricket, trivia

Is   cricket the  second number game after football in terms of its  popularity? but some people are saying that squash is most playing game after football. I think cricket is most playing game after football.

Comment: Where? In a specific region or globally?

Comment: I am talking globally!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the criteria being used.

According to [Total Sportek](https://www.totalsportek.com/most-popular-sports/), Cricket is the **3rd** most popular sport after Football and Basketball, based on the following 13 criteria:

- Global base & audience
- TV  Viewership numbers
- Number Professional leagues around the world
- TV rights deals
- Endorsement & Sponsorship deals
- Average athlete salary in top league
- Biggest competition & (number of countries represented)
- Social media presence
- Prominence in sports headlines on media outlets (websites, tv)
- Relevancy through the year
- Regional dominance
- Gender equality
- Accessible to general public worldwide

However, there are many other lists with other results based on other criteria.

For example, [World Atlas](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/what-are-the-most-popular-sports-in-the-world.html) claims Cricket is **2nd** while Basketball is **7th** based solely on global following (i.e. the number of fans).

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon the people whom they prefer the most as many leagues like
1= PSL
2= IPL
3=BPL
these all leagues are becoming the famous and become the cause of entertainment around the world  . Now people are prefer these types of leagues the most because these matches are seen by millions of people live on internet and mostly on channels in Asia sides so i think cricket is getting more popular and after football leagues.